# Javascript - Get index of element in arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I get the index of an element in Arrow Function?

Here is my code:

```
  this.data.forEach(element => {
    //console.log(index); //I want to get this index
      console.log(element);
  });
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `forEach` has several parameters, the second is the index.

Comment: This is not a question about `angular` or `angularjs`. Please stop adding those tags.

Comment: "Angularjs is a JavaScript Language"? What are you babbling about? Angularjs is not a language it is a framework and as such this question has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya `angularjs` is not a language - it is a framework. Your question is about how the parameters to `.forEach()` work, which is specific to JavaScript. It has nothing to do with the `angularjs` framework. By that logic, you should also tag React, Backbone, Vue, etc. That is **not** the purpose of tags.

Comment: @bambam I think the es-6 tag should stay on, since this question does specifically ask about arrow functions, which is an es-6 specific feature

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure about that either - I didn't think that the question how to pass parameters to a function is specific enough to keep the es6 tag. It boils down to a basic javascript question... @mhodges

Comment: @bambam Yeah, I totally see your point. I think I would side with keeping it, since adding a second parameter to an arrow function requires different syntax (wrapping with `()`). Someone may know that the second parameter of `.forEach()` is the index, they just may not be sure how to actually access it via the arrow function because they may not know they need to use wrapping parens. I think that is the OP's issue here, but I'm not positive.

Comment: As long as he keeps out angularjs I'm fine with that too :-D @mhodges

Comment: @bambam Haha true!

Comment: Hi @SurjeetBhadauriya pls help my friend on this.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59468510/12590864

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can get index by adding another parameter to array function,

```
this.data.forEach((element, index) = > {
  console.log(index); //I want to get this index
  console.log(element);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can directly get the index without using forEach if your purpose is just to get index,

```
console.log(this.data.findIndex(elem => elem === element));
```

or with .forEach, you can get the index from the second parameter

```
this.data.forEach((element, index) = > {
  console.log(index); 
});
```

Comment: `.findIndex()` accepts a comparator function as a parameter. Should be `this.data.findIndex(elem => elem === element)`